# Swift - Construct a sentence from array of <AnyObject>

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

Good day! I'm building an app that needs to construct a sentence from the data from Core Data. I have this:

```
var players = Array<AnyObject> = []
@IBOutlet weak var sentenceLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Orders")
        players = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!
      }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return players.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("checkCell") as! SummaryCustomCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = SummaryCustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "checkCell")
    }
    var data: NSManagedObject = players[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject

    cell.playerNameLabel.text = data.valueForKey("playerName") as? String
    cell.teamLabel.text = data.valueForKey("team") as? String
    cell.yearsLabel.text = data.valueForKey("yearsOfPlaying") as? String

    for var i = 0; i < players.count;i++ {
            var dataLooped: NSManagedObject = myOrders[i] as! NSManagedObject
            var playerName = dataLooped.valueForKey("playerName") as? String
            var team = dataLooped.valueForKey("team") as? String
            var years = dataLooped.valueForKey("yearsOfPlaying") as? String

            var constructedSentence: NSString = NSString(format: "%@ was playing for %@ for %@ years.", playerName, team, years)
                sentenceLabel.text = constructedSentence as! String

            }

        }


    return cell
}
```

Then it gives only the last row in the database. It must loop the sentence in a single string. For example. `"Kobe Bryant was playing for LA Lakers for 5 years; Lebron James was playing for Cavs for 3 years." and so on..`

How can I implement this? Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you need to do with that string ?

Comment: I want to show it as a sentence in a label. But will add and add more based on the data on database. Like this `"Kobe Bryant was playing for LA Lakers for 5 years; Lebron James was playing for Cavs for 3 years."` it will be just separated by `;`

Comment: I guess you want the sentence built out of the three other labels in the **current** row rather than the same sequence of sentences in **all** rows

Comment: Is the yearsOfPlaying = 5 or do you need to count it? Is the data set that you are trying to count player name and match the team then calculate the years? Show and example of how the data is laid out. To me it looks like you have over complicated it maybe.